# Creating SSL network listener in glassfish4 - how to enter new keystore password?

Tags: ssl, glassfish-4

The goal is to enable SSL on created network listener, by using `.jks` file which contains required certificates:

[image]

But entered `someKeystore.jks` is password protected, and `https` connection is not working. How can I enter this keystore password in glassfish4?